# Getting error while making dash wallet

Tags: ubuntu, make, cpp

I just run successfully run the commands

```
./autogen.sh
./configure
```

Then I get some error while running

```
make
```

The errors is followings

```
Making all in src
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/myname/Documents/dash-master/src'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/myname/Documents/dash-master/src'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/myname/Documents/dash-master'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/myname/Documents/dash-master'
CXX      bls/libdashconsensus_la-bls.lo
In file included from bls/bls.cpp:5:0:
bls/bls.h:14:27: fatal error: chiabls/bls.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:9319: recipe for target 'bls/libdashconsensus_la-bls.lo' failed
make[2]: *** [bls/libdashconsensus_la-bls.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/myname/Documents/dash-master/src'
Makefile:10949: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/myname/Documents/dash-master/src'
Makefile:688: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://github.com/dashpay/dash/blob/master/doc/build-generic.md#note-on-old-build-instructions):

> In the past, the build documentation contained instructions on how to build Dash with system-wide installed dependencies like BerkeleyDB 4.8, boost and Qt. Building this way is considered deprecated and only building with the depends prefix is supported today.

```
$ cd depends
$ make -j4 # Choose a good -j value, depending on the number of CPU cores available
$ cd ..
```